# Get-ADgroupmember FSP accounts issue

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to export a list of users from a 'domain local' group. This group has users from its own domain and from external domains. When running the Get-ADgroupmember cmdlet, it fails when it finds a ghost FSP and then stop searching within the group. 
While reading the suggestions as alternative solution for this issue, people have recommended using Get-ADGroup, but could not find a way to return the name or the SamAccountName for external users (Users from trusted domains).

Do you guys know any alternative solution for the issue with get-adgroupmember when trying to get deleted FSP objects without removing its membership from the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will work or not but you can try to use ADSI directly through .NET:

```
$s = [adsisearcher]'(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=GroupCN))'
$r = $s.findone()

$r.properties.member
```

should return the distinguished name of all the users in the group.  you can then use those values with the powershell aD cmdlets to try and get any other desired attributes from those users or make ADSI references to each of them to get the desired attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

Cool, yes. I may go that direction.
Running that command it brings me all the members, and the external with their SSID. 
I may translate the SSID to SamaccountName and then the ones that fail to translate, they would be the orphan ones... I can just ignore them then...
Thanks for your help thepip3r